# Nested Object destructuring

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

When destructuring objects, I sometimes run into the issue of not knowing whether or not keys exist, and then trying to pull values from them. This obviously errors, since they are undefined. For example:

Expecting something like this:

```
{ user: { name: { first: 'Trey', last: 'Hakanson' } } }
```

But  I actually get this:

```
{ user: {} }
```

and attempting to destructure like this errors:

```
const { user: { name: { first: firstName, last: lastName } } } = data
```

is there any way to assign a default value earlier in the deconstruction? Such as assigning `name = { first: 'Hello', last: 'World' }` if the `name` key doesn't exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const { user: { name: { first: firstName = 'firstName', last: lastName = 'lastName' } = {} } = {} } = data
```

Comment: This guards against `name` being `undefined`, but still errors if `name` is `null` right? Any way to protect against `name` being either `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: Don't think so, null is actually a value. Undefined just means it has not been defined that value

Answer (score -1):

You can assign default values if the value is falsy value or undefined in your case. In javascript the default values can be assigned by using the `||` operator.

If the first operand is falsy `(false, null, undefined, "",0)` then it returns the second operand. Otherwise, it returns the first operand. This provides a convenient way to specify default values

```
var myDefaultName = name || { first: 'Hello', last: 'World' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm currently using this solution, I was looking for a solution using only es6 deconstruction though