# Cleaner way to destructure nested objects with defaults?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have a nested object which may have stuff missing:

```
const unreliableObject = {
    id: 10,
    nestedObject: { // may be missing
        id: 11 // may also be missing
    }
}
```

Now say I want to get the inner id. I *can* do the following

```
const { nestedObject: { id: key = -1 } = {key: -1} } = unreliableObject;
console.log(key);
```

Is there a better way? Something where I'm not defining `{key: -1}` twice, nor using an empty object (we have lint rules in place), and I still want to default key in that case.

Comment: `var { nestedObject: { id: key = -1 } = {}} = unreliableObject;` or maybe [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors/42349521).

Comment: That could work, but we are using a lint rule to prevent empty objects. I could use lodash's `get` and use the defaults.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Object destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171421/nested-object-destructuring)

Comment: @Pureferret Maybe you should reconsider that linter rule when it makes no sense

Comment: @Bergi I will have a word with the powers that be....

Comment: @adiga except I'm doing that already

Comment: 1) Not really. The dupe has an answer which is same as what @str suggested with an empty object `{}` as default 2) It's a way of linking it to the dupe to help future visitors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Comment: @adiga I'm doing as close as I can. I'll edit to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to accept a path notation similar to [Lodash's get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) and the use of a Proxy object then you can turn `p['x.y.z']` into a safe `p.x.y.z` operation:

```js
const {'x.y.z': a = 42} = path({});
const {'x.y.z': b = 42} = path({x: {}});
const {'x.y.z': c = 42} = path({x: {z: {}}});
const {'x.y.z': d = 42} = path({x: {y: {z: 999}}});

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

```html
<script>
const path = obj =>
  new Proxy(obj, {
    get(o, k) {
      const [head, ...tail] = k.split('.'); 
      return tail.length === 0 ?
        o[head] :
        path(o[head] != null ? o[head] : {})[tail.join('.')];
    }
  });
</script>
```

---

If you're willing to not use destructuring and accept even more Proxy magic, then we could do other crazy things like **turning properties into functions!**

```js
const p = path(/* some object */);
p.x.y.z(42);
// either the value at 'x.y.z' or 42
```

```js
const a = path({});
const b = path({x: {}});
const c = path({x: {z: {}}});
const d = path({x: {y: {z: 999}}});

console.log(a.x.y.z(42),
            b.x.y.z(42),
            c.x.y.z(42),
            d.x.y.z(42));
```

```html
<script>
const path = obj =>
  new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (o, k) =>
      o[k] == null
        ? path(x => x)
        : typeof o[k] === 'object'
          ? path(o[k])
          : () => o[k] });
</script>
```

---

This is probably overengineered but I wanted to toy with Proxy anyway ;) Perhaps this helps though.